# Animating link container in css

Tags: html, css

I was able to make to rectangle surrounding my links expand as I wanted but it's a bit too fast

My new code is this:

```css
a:link, a:visited {
  background-color: #F2AA52;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}

a:hover {
    width: 100%;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

I'm almost done with this but it goes to `100%` width a little too fast, is there a way to make it go smoother? (instead of it going from `30%` width to `100%` width instantly, being able to see it progressively getting bigger in like `1.5`s?)

Comment: Can you add a snippest of your html code?

Comment: While text stays same means ?

Comment: Problem was in giving it as padding.

Comment: I think you just need to add `transition:all 1s;` to your css for `a`. Although the question is very vague.

Comment: While text stays same means ? – Abin Thaha 3 mins ago : i mean i want the text to stay at the same place

Comment: @gsol, can you check the solution I have added ?

Comment: @AbinThaha just did and commented on it, it's almost perfect now as i used youre width:100% line to do what i wanted but it's just slightly too fast so i have to work on the speed of the animation

Comment: @KeshavBajaj i tried editing my code and being a little more precise in what i'm asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
a:link, a:visited {
  background-color: #F2AA52;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
a:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href='google.com'>Hi</a>
```

Check this out, I have replaced the padding with width. Hence the transition is working as expected

Comment: This is almost working as i want but it changes the initial size of my orange rectangles, i will try combining your solution with my code and see if i make any progress, thanks!

Comment: Ok, post in case if its not working as expected. we can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the  `transition: all 0.3s ease;` line but it still won't give me a smooth transition, it goes from "base state" to "100% width" instantly, even though it works in your code snippet.

EDIT: now i got it working i had to give it a base width for it to work as i wanted. Thank you!

Is there a way to change my question to "Resolved"?